# How to tell Debian not to worry about certain dependencies?

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I'm using docker to provide an mta.

But it's broken apt because it won't let me install packages that need an mta (e.g. `bsd-mailx`).

For individual packages I can force it; download the package and use `dpkg -f -i package.deb` but that still leaves apt fretting about an unresolved dependency, which prevents me installing other packages that are nothing to do with the MTA.

e.g.

```
$ apt install silversearcher-ag
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bsd-mailx : Depends: default-mta or
                      mail-transport-agent
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Is there a way to tell it that there *is* a `mail-transport-agent` package installed? (I'm on Debian 9)

Comment: @stephen-kitt thank you, tha's exactly what I needed but had failed to find searching this site! Appreciate your time.